# Microsoft 365, how to setup a single user with multiple emails on different domains?

Tags: office365, microsoft365, microsoft-exchange

On MS 365, for a single user I'd like to setup two real emails:
`username@mydomain.com` and `username@myotherdomain.com`.

`user@mydomain.com` is well setup. Now I'm trying to add `username@myotherdomain.com`.

So far I tried to add `username@myotherdomain.com`

- as an aliases but it's not a real email
- as a distribution list that can receive email from outside the organisation and where `user@mydomain.com` can "Send As". It doesn't work. I tried to send an email to it via gmail and it failed and I tried to send an from it but it said that I don't have the "on behalf rights" (I've setup the "Send as" rights not the "on behalf of" ones...)
- as a shared mailbox. It almost worked. I does with `anyotherusername@myotherdomain.com` but not with `username@myotherdomain.com`

Does anyone know how to achieve what should be a simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that when I create `username@myotherdomain.com`, it automatically tries to create an alias `username@mydomain.com`. And this is why it fails. So I found the following workardound that works.

1. I create `username2@mytoherdoamin.com` and save
2. I edit `username2@myotherdomain.com` to delete the aliases (including `username2@mydomain.com` then) and update the email to be `username@myotherdomain.com` and I save.